# C program read input file and output with "\n" new line every 50 characters

Tags: c

```
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
  int c;

  while((c = getc(ifp))!= EOF)
    putc(c,ofp);
}
```

So, I have try:

```
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
  int c;
  int count = 0;

  while((c = getc(ifp))!= EOF)
    if(count == 50){
     putc("\n",ofp);//This didnt work
     count = 0;
     }
    putc(c,ofp);
}
```

Am I supposed to use some type of pointers?  Im not too good with C pointers, does anyone know?  Thank you.

Comment: Why do you check if count=0 when you want to do a new line every 50 chars?  Also, when do you increment count?

Comment: Sorry typo, but I dont think using putc works to add a new line to stdo.

Comment: suggest using puts() rather than putc(), so that "\n" will be properly output, when outputing the newline.  Then use putc() when only echoing the character read from the input file.  Oh, and increment 'count' somewhere in that while loop/

Answer (score 2):

your `putc` is attempting to output a string, which is actually a pointer.  `putc` just takes the initial 8 bits as a char of the variable, which is most certainly not `\n` in this case.

You probably want (note the single quotes):

```
putc('\n', ofp);
```

If you are using windows, you may need to output `\r\n` to get the desired result.

Finally, your loop isn't testing for every 50 characters, it's outputting the value on each loop iteration.  I assume you have done that as a test.

Comment: I just tested single quotes, but it didnt work.  I believe I have to use some type of pointer to add the new line.

Comment: Nope.  Check the [putc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putc).  The first parameter is not a pointer, but an immediate value.  (Note: the man page says int, but actually it's treated as a char, usually.  C is weird that way).

Answer (score 2):

Couple of issues:

1. Your `while` loop needs braces
2. `'\n'` not `"\n"`
3. increment `count`

Your final code should look like this:

```
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
  int c;
  int count = 0;

  while((c = getc(ifp))!= EOF){
    if(count == 50){
      putc('\n',ofp);//This didnt work
      count = 0;
    }
    putc(c,ofp);
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont believe using putc or '\n' will work.  Have to find some pointer to add the new line i believe.

Comment: I found it, posted at the bottom, it was so simple .

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Paul's correct answer, you can use modulo to decide when to output the newline:

```
if(++count % 50 == 0){
    putc('\n', ofp);
}
```

Comment: Compiler love letters! :) `++count % 50 || putc('\n', ofp);`

Answer (score 0):

Answer was :

```
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
  int c;
  int count = 0;

  while((c = getc(ifp))!= EOF)
    if(count == 50){
     printf("\n");
     putc(c,ofp);
     count = 0;
     }
    else
    putc(c,ofp);

    count++;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how it is working.. count is incremented outside of loop... anyway happy coding..